# bind javascript function to input control on window load

Tags: javascript, html

I amm develloping  an web form with multiple text box with same css class.
and i want to bind a specific method to all these textboxes who use that class.
 belows are my codes

```
 window.onload = function ()
    {

        var tObj = document.getElementsByClassName('exa');
        for (var i = 0; i < tObj.length; i++) {               
            tObj[i].onblur(convertAmount(event,this));
        }
    }
```

the another function 'convertAmount()' is below

```
function convertAmount(evt, obj) {
        if (obj.value != "") {

            var num = parseFloat(obj.value);
            num = Math.round((num + 0.00001) * 100) / 100;
            obj.value = num.toFixed(2);
        }
        else {
            obj.value = "0.00";
        }
    }
```

html codes

```
<div>  
        <input type="text" id="finalvalue" class="exa"/>
        <input type="text" id="grossvalue" class="exa"/>
    <div>
```

when browser load first time only '0.00' values are coming on those text boxes. but when i type some values on those text boxes and press tab its not working! please help what is wrong here

Comment: where should i write the .bind keyword?

Comment: My bad! `onBlur` should be assignment. Yes you will have to bind but you will have to assign it. [Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynp8b86L/)

Comment: are you saying for each textbox we have to write code onblur event ?

Comment: No. You will have to write 1 function that you already have. Now just set this function as `.onBlur = convertAmount;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented before, you should  assign a `eventHandler` and not pass it as callback.

So you code would be:

```
tObj[i].onblur = convertAmount.bind(this, event, this);
```

Also, event is default argument for any eventListener and current object/element is automatically binded to it, so above code can be simplified to

```
tObj[i].onblur = convertAmount;
```

This will bind the context and you will get all properties in `this`.

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynp8b86L/1/)

**Note:** you should use `addEventListener` instead. `onBlur =` will replace all previous events. `addEventListener` will add another one.

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ynp8b86L/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/yuvakom/nztso6kh/) helpful to you.

```
<div>  
        <input type="text" id="finalvalue" class="exa"/>
        <input type="text" id="grossvalue" class="exa"/>
    <div>


    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.exa').each(function(index,value){
    $(this).attr('onblur',convertAmount(event,$(this)))
    })


    })

    function convertAmount(evt, obj) {
    if (obj != "") {
    $(obj).val('0.00')
        }
        else {
            $(obj).val('0.00')
        }


    }
```

Comment: jQuery is not tagged in question. You should confirm from OP before answering it